# How do you find the sample size given R output that omits the degrees of freedom?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, anova, interpretation

All I am given is the following information and asked to find the sample size. I just cannot see where to start. I am wondering if some of the info on the document got cut off because I have no idea

```
>lm(formula = sales ~ price + advert + I(advert^2), data =
Andy)
Coefficients: Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 109.7190 6.7990 16.137 < 2e-16 ***
price -7.6400 1.0459 -7.304 3.24e-10 ***
advert 12.1512 3.5562 3.417 0.00105 **
I(advert^2) -2.7680 0.9406 -2.943 0.00439 **
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

>
(Intercept) price advert I(advert^2)
(Intercept) 46.227019 -6.42611301 -11.6009601 2.93902634
price -6.426113 1.09398815 0.3004062 -0.08561906
advert -11.600960 0.30040624 12.6463020 -3.28874574
I(advert^2) 2.939026 -0.08561906 -3.2887457 0.88477357
```

Comment: You have the $t$-value and the $p$-value. From this, you can deduce the residual degrees of freedom (e.g. using the values from `advert`) and from those, you can deduce the sample size. In this case, the sample size is the residual degrees of freedom + 4.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, some of the output has been removed.  And while it would be much more straightforward to obtain the sample size with the information that was removed, there is another way to obtain the requested information.

As I am more than 95% confident that this is a homework question (as this is the type of homework question I give to my students), I will provide a framework on how to answer the question.

If you had the degrees of freedom from this output, you can use the fact that the sum of the error degrees of freedom and the model degrees of freedom give the total degrees of freedom:
$$df_{\text{total}} = df_{\text{model}} + df_{\text{error}}$$
The model degrees of freedom is the number of instrumental variables in the model (the number of rows in the coefficients table except for the intercept).

The total degrees of freedom is always one less than the sample size.

Again, the part of the output that was omitted was the part that lists these two degrees of freedom or the part that lists just the error degrees of freedom.  So, we will use the protocol recommended by @COOLSerdash.

I will provided an explanation using R and the pt(·) function.  Using the p-value for the advert partial slope, plug this into the function

```
pt(0.00105/2, 5)
```

You will note that I divided the p-value in half (as the output reports a two-tailed p-value) and I chose 5 as my degree of freedom.  Here is the issue.  You need to play with this last value to get the answer.  That is to say, you need to plug in different values until you 3.417.  (Actually, as this function is reporting the left critical value, the output would be -3.417...but the idea is the same...keep changing the degrees of freedom until you obtain the corresponding t-ratio reported in the output.)

I have confirmed that the other partial slopes' p-values and t-ratios return the same degree of freedom.  So, you could do the same with either of the p-values in the last 3 rows of the coefficients table from this output.

I hope this helps.